# Derivation of mean-variance portfolio weights as closed-form analytical solution from Lagrangean equations

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, optimization, mean-variance

I am trying to find a closed form solution for the constrained MVO problem below.

$\max_w  w'\mu - \frac{\lambda}{2}w'\Sigma w $ 
s.t. $w'$**1** = 1

The Lagrange for the objective is $L(w, \gamma) = w'\mu - \frac{\lambda}{2}w'\Sigma w -\gamma(w'$**1** - 1).

The first order conditions are:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w} = \mu - \lambda \Sigma w - \gamma$ **1** = 0 
Hence, $w = \frac{1}{\lambda}\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-\gamma$ **1**) $\hspace{1cm} [1]$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \gamma} = w'$**1** - 1 = 0 
Hence, $w$'**1** = 1 $\hspace{1cm} [2]$

Just to clarify, $\gamma$ is a real number; **1**, $\mu$ have dimensions of Nx1; $\Sigma$ has dimension of NxN.

Substitute [1] into [2] 
$[\frac{1}{\lambda}\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-\gamma$ **1**$)]'$**1** = 1 
$(\mu-\gamma 1)'\Sigma^{-1} $ **1** = $\lambda$

I am unable to express $\gamma \text{ in terms of } \Sigma, \mu, \lambda$, to substitute it into [1] to write a solution for $w$.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Rewrite your FOC as a linear equation system in matrix notation. Solve for $x$ using the blockwise matrix inversion theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix

Comment: If that doesn’t help you I can elaborate in an answer

Comment: @Kermittfrog could you please elaborate? I tried writing down the FOCs but couldn't see where I should apply the inversion theorem. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's stick with the nomenclature in the literature and let $\gamma$ denote the decision maker's risk aversion coefficient. The optimization problem is

$$
\max_{\mathrm{w}} \mathrm{w}^T\mathrm{\mu}-\frac{1}{2}\gamma \mathrm{w}^T\mathrm{\Sigma}\mathrm{w} \quad s.t. \mathrm{w}^T\mathrm{e}=1
$$
where $e$ denotes a vector of ones. The corresponding Lagrangean reads:
$$
L(\mathrm{w},\lambda)= \mathrm{w}^T\mathrm{\mu}-\frac{1}{2}\gamma \mathrm{w}^T\mathrm{\Sigma}\mathrm{w} -\lambda\left( \mathrm{w}^T\mathrm{e}-1\right)
$$

The first order conditions are linear:
\begin{align}
L_w&=\mathrm{\mu}-\gamma\mathrm{\Sigma}\mathrm{w}-\lambda\mathrm{e}=!=0\\
L_{\lambda}&=\mathrm{e}^T\mathrm{w}=!=1
\end{align}

We can formulate this as a linear system as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma\mathrm{\Sigma} & \mathrm{e}\\
\mathrm{e}^T & 0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{w}\\
\lambda\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{\mu} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and hence

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{w^*}\\
\lambda^*\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma\mathrm{\Sigma} & \mathrm{e}\\
\mathrm{e}^T & 0\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{\mu} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c_{11} & c_{12} \\ c_{21} & c_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{\mu} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

This is where we use the [block matrix inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) . We *know* that $w^*$ is given by the first row of the inverted matrix times the constraint vector,

$$
\mathrm{w}^*=c_{11}\mathrm{\mu}+c_{12}
$$
Looking up the two inversions from wiki, we find

$$
c_{11}=\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathrm{\Sigma}^{-1}-\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathrm{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathrm{e}\left(\mathrm{e}^T\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathrm{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathrm{e}\right)^{-1}\mathrm{e}^T\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathrm{\Sigma}^{-1}
$$
and
$$
c_{12}=\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathrm{\Sigma^{-1}}\mathrm{e}\left(\mathrm{e}^T\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathrm{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathrm{e}\right)^{-1}=\frac{\mathrm{\Sigma^{-1} e}}{\mathrm{e}^T\mathrm{\Sigma^{-1} e}}
$$

Let us introduce the following

\begin{align}
a&=\mathrm{e}^T\mathrm{\Sigma^{-1}}\mathrm{e}\\
b&=\mathrm{e}^T\mathrm{\Sigma^{-1}}\mathrm{\mu}\\
w_{MVP}&=\frac{\mathrm{\Sigma^{-1} e}}{\mathrm{e}^T\mathrm{\Sigma^{-1} e}}\\
w_{Tangency}&=\frac{\mathrm{\Sigma^{-1} \mu}}{\mathrm{e}^T\mathrm{\Sigma^{-1} \mu}}
\end{align}
Note that, conveniently, the two portfolios are the minimum-variance portfolio and the tangency portfolio. Then, $c_{12}\mu$ simplifies to
$$
c_{12}\mathrm{\mu}=\frac{1}{\gamma}bw_{Tangency}-\frac{1}{\gamma}w_{MVP}b
$$

and thus

$$
w^* = w_{MVP} + \frac{1}{\gamma}b\left(w_{Tangency}-w_{MVP}\right)
$$

Finally, we note that $E(MVP)=\frac{b}{a}$, and $V(MVP)=\frac{1}{a}$. Thus, we may ultimately replace $b$ in equation above and arrive at

$$
w^* = w_{MVP} + \frac{1}{\gamma}\frac{\mu_{MVP}}{\sigma_{MVP}^2}\left(w_{Tangency}-w_{MVP}\right)
$$

Comment: FOC $L_w=\mathrm{\mu}-\mathrm{\Sigma}\mathrm{w}-\lambda\mathrm{e}=!=0$ doesn't match the first row of the linear system that follows because it missed $\gamma$

Comment: Yep, thanks. Corrected it.

Comment: i see the "inverted matrix" and "constraint vector", but is there a name for the matrix consisting of $c$'s, and what its elements are for?. it looks like *it* is the inverted matrix

Comment: It is the inverse of the FOC.